# AWS SDK for React Native supported services

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

How stable are the listed services for AWS SDK for React Native?

I have a front-end developed in React Native and want to utilize AWS cloud services. My concern is that the SDK is just a preview with claims to support S3, Lambda, and SNS. I'd like to know if anyone has had success using these services in their React Native apps and if there are any gotchas I should be aware of.

Thanks!

Announcing the AWS SDK for React Native: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-the-aws-sdk-for-react-native/

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the open issues and posting your question at the project's GitHub page: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native/issues

Comment: Hi Eugene, I'm also following this project. I want to do an application using javascript and dynamoDB without AWS Lambda, what do you think?

Comment: Ugh! This seems so hacky. I want to use S3 for video hosting and RDB for  React Native. Are there any authentication alternatives I could use? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I have implement the aws-react-native-sdk with cognito. And found some errors but successfully implement it. If you are planning to implement it, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the new AWS Amplify library released to the official AWS repo which has React Native support: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

You can install via npm:

```
npm install aws-amplify-react-native
```

Then import into your project:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify-react-native'
```

There are modules for wrapping your React Native Components with HOCs for tasks such as Authentication, Analytics, APIs, Storage, etc.